# How to override Django Admin AutoComplete widget wrapper

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-admin

I'm trying to override the `AutoComplete` widget in the admin.  This field is usually wrapped in another widget: `RelatedFieldWrapper` which I need to pass a dynamic variable to after a file has been uploaded.

More context:  what I do is I fetch some values from a file, and use them as initial data to create a bunch of inline formsets (that can be viewed and edited before saving). This is fine, but one of the columns is an `Autocomplete`. I can't pass data to that field since it needs a foreign key I won't know in advance, so I'm sending the data to that field as extra text (aka a hint) in the Autocomplete field's wrapper so the user knows what item to actually search for in the actual autocomplete.

So far this is what I have:

```py
class ChartItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    hint = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Title.objects.none()) # autocomplete field

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChartItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # if there's a hint, we pass it to a custom wrapper around the autocomplete
        if 'hint' in self.initial:
            hint = self.initial['hint']
            self.fields['title'].widget = AutoCompleteWrapperWithHint(
             AutocompleteSelect(self.instance._meta.get_field('title').remote_field, site._registry.get(Title).admin_site,), 
             self.instance._meta.get_field('title').remote_field, site._registry.get(Chart).admin_site, hint=hint)
```

Custom wrapper:

```py
class AutoCompleteWrapperWithHint(RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper):
    """
    This class is a wrapper to a given widget to add the add icon for the
    admin interface.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.hint = kwargs.pop('hint')
        super(AutoCompleteWrapperWithHint, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's ugly but it works kinda, but I'm getting this error:
`'tuple' object has no attribute 'field'`

After much digging I saw it's because the Autocomplete widget's choices attribute don't have the field attribute. I guess in my overwrite the field is not being properly initialized as `ModelChoiceIterator` and I don't know how to fix that. This is the section it fails per traceback.

```
...lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py in <setcomp>

            print(dir(self.choices))
            """Return selected options based on the ModelChoiceIterator."""
            default = (None, [], 0)
            groups = [default]
            has_selected = False
            selected_choices = {
                str(v) for v in value
                if str(v) not in self.choices.field.empty_values
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

I eventually got around this, but I'll leave what I did here in case anyone runs into the same issue overriding these widgets. My custom widget wasn't getting the queryset attribute because I was working with manually passed `initial` data, I'm assuming.
So I needed to set the widget and queryset iterator (`Title.objects.none()`) *after* initialization like below:

```py
class ChartItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    hint = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChartItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'hint' in self.initial:
            hint = self.initial['hint']
            widget = AutoCompleteWrapperWithHint(
                    AutocompleteSelect(self.instance._meta.get_field('title').remote_field, site._registry.get(Title).admin_site,),
                    self.instance._meta.get_field('title').remote_field, site._registry.get(Chart).admin_site, hint=hint
                )
            self.fields['title'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Title.objects.none(), widget=widget)
```